# Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string al usar un where

Tags: laravel

hola estoy tratando de llenar una variable con los datos de contacto del usuario y verificarla con un var_dump , esta es la consulta que utilizo:

```
   $contacto=DB::table('contactos')
                ->join('redes_sociales','redes_sociales.rs_id','=','contactos.rs_id')
                ->join('users','users.usu_id','=','contactos.usu_id')
                ->select('contactos.co_nom','redes_sociales.rs_nom')
                ->where('contactos.usu_id','=',$usu_id)
                ->get();
    
                var_dump($contacto);
```

Este es el error que me devuelve:
ErrorException
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

pero si saco el ->where la consulta se ejecuta,la variable se carga y se muestra pero muestra todos los datos de la tabla contacto

utilizo la misma consulta en postgre con el where y si funciona trayéndome los datos del usuario.

```
Select contactos.co_nom , redes_sociales.rs_nom from contactos
inner join redes_sociales on contactos.rs_id = redes_sociales.rs_id 
inner join users on contactos.usu_id = users.usu_id
where contactos.usu_id = 2
```

¿Como puedo corregir para mostrar los datos de contacto del usuario?

Comment: Has un `dump($usu_id)` y revisa el tipo de dato, debe ser un string, un bool, un number, pero no objetos o arreglos.

Comment: $usu_id lo tomo de otra consulta y en el var_dump me muestra el 2 que corresponde al id del usuario

Comment: Y si pones `->where('contactos.usu_id','=',2)` pasa lo mismo?